# High frequency thread with fixed frequency

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to execute a task at a high frequency in python, where the task execution time is high relative to the period.

Normally, I would use a thread which re-posts itself, for example:

```
from threading import Thread

class PeriodicThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            self.f(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            sleep(self.period)
```

However, this is only suitable where the execution time of `self.f` is negligible compared to `self.period`.

My initial thoughts on how to do this would involve either noting the start time of this loop, and adjusting the sleep time appropriately, or basing the thread off a counting semaphore that is incremented by another thread.

Both of these seem unnecessarily convoluted.  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Just use `time.sleep(x)`.

Comment: I don't think "noting the start time of this loop, and adjusting the sleep time appropriately" is unnecessarily convoluted. It's what I'd do.

Comment: @Tim agreed. Before I read that far I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: alternatively have two threads where a very light timer thread wakes a worker thread. But I agree with @Tim, THAT would be unnecessarily convoluted. Also remember that Python's threading support sucks due to the GIL.

Comment: @Tim - maybe I've been doing too much embedded development lately, but I don't like having the overhead of two system calls (to `time.time`) as well as some math in order to determine the sleep time

Comment: @Sapi: A call to `time.time()` takes about 0.26 usec on my machine. What's the frequency of your task?

Comment: I'm not sure about the overhead or the timing resolution, but have you thought about the builtin `Timer` class? http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects